# Why does cooling down thermal imaging cameras increase sensitivity?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation, camera

A lot of high-sensitivity thermal cameras and sensors are (cryogenically) cooled down to low temperatures to achieve these high sensitivities. For example. the Stinger missile, and the James Webb Space Telescope, are both cooled down to extremely low temperatures before usage.

How does decreasing the temperature of the thermal imaging equipment increase sensitivity? What equations or engineering problems are at play here to require this cooling, as opposed to keeping it at a higher temperature?

Comment: It doesn't increase sensitivity: It increases the [_signal to noise ratio_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) by decreasing the [_noise floor_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_floor). It's just like how turning down the music in the room makes it easier to hear what the person on the telephone is saying to you.

Answer (score 4):

For temperature measurement instruments as used in those applications, you want to make sure you are measuring the temperature of the *target* and not the *instrument*. This is particularly true for electronic sensors intended to measure very low temperatures, or high temperature objects that are very, very far away. In these cases, the temperature of the instrument can easily overwhelm the sensor and you wind up measuring its temperature and not that of the target.

One way to fight this tendency is to cool the instrument down so as to reduce the amount of interfering signal and let you "see" instead the target itself. With the thermal "noise" thus reduced, you can more easily pick out weak signals from far away.